# Android. Cannot parse json string from bundle

Tags: android, gson, bundle, android-json

I'm trying to parse json string from bundle to object.
But I get error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
> at line 1 column 2 path $

Here is my code:

```
val jsonString = bundle.getString(key)
val type = Info::class.java
val json = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type)
```

My `Info` data class:

```
data class Info(
   val id: Long,
   val canProceed: Boolean,
   val wasAdded: Boolean,
)
```

I tried to evaluate the expression and I see that `bundle.getString(key)` returns

```
"{\"id\":6067857,\"canProceed\":false,\"wasAdded\":false}"
```

Everything looks good, but for some reason I'm getting the error I described above. Moreover, if in the expression evaluation mode I copy the return value from the `bundle.getString(key)` and manually substitute it, as here:

```
Gson().fromJson("{\"id\":6067857,\"canProceed\":false,\"wasAdded\":false}", type)
```

then everything works well, I get the object. What could be the problem ?

Please help me.

P.S.
What I pass to my bundle:

```
val info: Info = Info(id = 6067857, canProceed = false, wasAdded = false) 
bundle.putString(key, Gson().toJson(info))
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of your bundle before you invoke bundle.getString(key)? Also what is the type you are passing to the fromJson method?

Comment: @tomerpacific, Please see the updated question, I have added information

Comment: Is that the exact code you are using, or have you simplified it? This problem sounds a lot like you are accidentally converting the value to JSON twice: `Info` -> JSON string -> JSON string containing JSON string

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are receiving indicates that ***Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1***, which means that Gson is expecting your JSON string to being with an object bracket `{` and not with an open quotes `"`.

What you have shared also shows you have a JSON string.

`bundle.getString(key)` returns a JSON string and as evidenced by what you wrote works properly.

If you write the code below, it should work:

```
val json = Gson().fromJson(bundle.getString(key), Info::class.java)
```